# How to determine URI of inspected resource using Firefox developer tools?

Tags: firefox, dom, firefox-developer-tools, dom-inspector

Using DOM Inspector in Firefox, it is easy to find the URI of the resource being inspected, even if that resource is part of Firefox's UI or is an IFRAME.

Using the built-in Firefox developer tools, how can this same task be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

> even if that resource is part of Firefox's UI or is an IFRAME.

If you want to inspect chrome elements you will need the [browser toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox)

> it is easy to find the URI of the resource being inspected

type `document.documentURI` in the console. For individual elements, simply look at them in the inspector, iframes will display as `<iframe src=...>` for example. Or select them and then interrogate their DOM representation in the console as `$0`, e.g. `$0.src` for iframes. `inspect($0)` or context menu -> inspect DOM properties will give you the whole set of dom properties for a node.

Comment: Thank you.  For anyone following along, note that `URI` must be capitalized.

Comment: I gave `document.documentURI` a try, and it is reporting the parent URI, not the URI of the actual element being inspected.  :(

Comment: Well, your question was not specific enough to distinguish those cases. You're always inspecting some document after all.

Comment: It's also possible I've stumbled on a bug in Firefox itself.  I need to take a close look at why the actual URI does not appear to be presented anywhere (well, anywhere I've found so far).